# Visiting Ukraine and Russia

Tags: visas, russia, ukraine

If I visit Kiev in Ukraine am I allowed to visit Russia at a later date? I would be travelling with a uk passport.

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to? Have you got the visas?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Because the countries are at war?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo, officially there're no war between those two countries. There's `anti-terrorist operation` against few ukrainian regions, and Russia gets blamed for supporting the rebels. But no direct war. Also, there were no limitations even for ukrainian citizens travelling to Russia, but there were limitations for russian citizens travelling to Ukraine (able-bodied males were banned from entering Ukraine few times for few month).

Comment: @user28434 Russia is currently occupying a large part of Ukraine. Even if there are no imminent armed actions, that fulfills every reasonable definition of war independent of any potential rebel support.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo, can you provide that "reasonable definition of war"?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo it is technically a conflict and not a war. Russia went to war with Georgia, it was called the Russo Georgian war. Ukraine has conflict with Russia but not war.

Comment: Yes, you're allowed... But be prepared for strict control at the border.

Comment: Can you prove this?

Comment: My friend from the Czech Republic comes to Ukraine every summer and at the end of summer, he usually visits his granny from Russia... So I know that it's possible to visit Russia after being in Ukraine and vice versa

Answer (score 2):

Yes, at least currently. There are no restrictions on entering Ukraine or Russia, even if you have visited the other country first.

Comment: Note that there might be problems entering Ukraine if you previously have entered the Crimea peninsula from Russia.

Comment: @mustaccio In practice only if you attempt to enter Ukraine directly from the Crimea peninsula, which is not possible for 'normal' tourists anyway. Ukrainian authorities sees it as prohibited for foreigners to enter Crimea from Russia, but there will be no traces of that in your travel document if you actually do it and Ukrainian authorities have no means to find out that you have been there.

Comment: That may be true, but some might wish to stay on the right side of the law, such as it is, even if it appears unenforceable at the moment.

Comment: If on the customs or during acquiring a visa it will be proven that you visited Crimea, you will be denied. It doesn't matter from which country or peninsula you travel at this point. A lot of Russian singers, bloggers and stuff were denied because of that, and most of them ended up in government "black" list of people who have a lifetime denial on entering Ukraine.